# Saving an nested list into a text file

Tags: python

Problem 1:
I want to create a program that gathers the Name, Age and Year Group from a person. I then want to save this into a nested loop.

```
AD = [["Name","Age","Year"],["Mark","15","11"]]

Inp = input("Name:")
AD.append(Inp)

Inp = input("Age:")
AD.append(Inp)

Inp = input("Year:") 
AD.append(Inp)

print(AD)
```

So I tried this...

```
Name:Jack
Age:14
Year:10
[['Name', 'Age', 'Year'], ['Mark', '15', '11'], 'Jack', '14', '10']
>>>
```

I want the result to look like...

```
Name:Jack
Age:14
Year:10
[['Name', 'Age', 'Year'], ['Mark', '15', '11'], ['Jack', '14', '10']]
>>>
```

Problem 2: I wish to then save and read from a File.

```
AD = [["Name","Age","Year"],["Mark","15","11"]]

Inp = input("Name:")
AD.append(Inp)

Inp = input("Age:")
AD.append(Inp)

Inp = input("Year:")
AD.append(Inp)

File = open("Details.txt","w")
File.write(AD)
File.close()

print(AD)
```

It then comes up with the problem of "write()" only using strings. How can easily save this information so when I'm given a name I can use it to find the 2 numbers related to it?

Thanks <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem 1:

```
AD = [["Name","Age","Year"],["Mark","15","11"]]

name = input("Name:")
age = input("Age:")
year = input("Year:") 

AD.append([name, age, year])
print(AD)
```

Problem 2:

writing

```
with open('Details.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join([','.join(person) for person in AD]))
```

reading

```
with open('Details.txt', 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
   AD = {}
   for line in list(lines)[1:]:
       name, age, year = line.split(',')
       AD[name] = [age, year]

name = input('Wich person do you want to squery? ')
age, year = AD[name]
print('This person has age {0} and year {1}'.format(age, year))
```

Comment: Tried this and got this result...                                                     Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Users\Mark\Documents\Python Programs\SignInFileStuff.py", line 9, in <module>
f.write('\n'([','.join(person) for person in AD]))
NameError: name 'f' is not defined

Comment: But keep in mind, this code does not work if there are multiple persons with the same name!

Comment: Thanks, however I'm getting another error....                              
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Users\Mark\Documents\Python Programs\SignInFileStuff.py", 
line 9, in <module> f.write('\n'([','.join(person) for person in AD]))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>>

Comment: Seems you did not copy paste correctly. Your traceback sais `f.write('\n'([','.join(person) for person in AD]))`, however, the code as it is writen in the above answer is: `f.write('\n'.join([','.join(person) for person in AD]))`.

Comment: This is a great help, thank you. You put the age and year into a print function, is there a way I could set the 2 numbers to a variable? As I wish to then get the person and test if they know year and age.

Comment: Of course. age and year are already in the variable `age` and `year`, as string though. If you want the numbers just use `int(age)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to save as a CSV file, then you can create a Panda data frame with 3 columns using these lists and then save as a CSV file. Later you can read the CSV file and fetch the values of "Age" and "Year" columns based on the value in "Name" column

Comment: Thanks for this, however I did look into it a bit, and it looks far too complex for me XD and I have 4 days to be able to do this and a lot of other stuff, I want to learn as little as possible to do this ;p

Comment: That's your perspective. No comments on that. But my suggestion is whenever you get time if you get to know about Pandas then you don't need to worry about time in future :-) Anyways All the best